# Serialize object to JToken

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a a JObject and I would like to set a property from a strongly typed object on it.

```
JObject["ProductionVersion"] = new ProductionVersion();
```

In order to do this, ProductVersion needs to be converted to a JToken.  How can I do this without having to serialize and deserialize the object as a JObject?

```
JObject["ProductVersion"] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message.ProductVersion))
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing..

1. So you have a `JObject` and you want a `JToken`?
   Well, a `JObject` *is* a `JToken`. Take a look at the inheritance hierarchy here: [`JObject class`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)
2. If what you meant is "I have a serializable object, and I want to convert it to a JToken without having to serialize and deserialize it again", then use this `JToken.FromObject(obj)`

Comment: Sorry about the confusing question, I updated it to be more clear.  JToken.FromObject is what I was looking for.  Had some issues with resharper intellisense and didn't see that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties by calling `Properties` on the `JObject`.

When you need to add a property, just add it using the `JProperty` constructor.

See the JSON.NET [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).